# Incomplete circle using CSS with divider in middle with text

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to make a circle being divided by the center with some text. But can not find any solution using css.

My HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.right, .left {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #9F9F9F;
    float: left;
    margin: 2px;
}
.wrap {
    margin: auto;
    width: 420px;
    position: relative;
}
.left:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 203px;
    top: 65px;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.right:before {
    content: "OR";
    border: 1px solid #9F9F9F;
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 175px;
    top: 65px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 5px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2re8d0cv/

My desired output is:

[image: This should be the out of]

After looking into my code and desired output you will understand. I don't want to use image there. as it will resolve problem I can not use image. I want to make it with full CSS only, but I also don't know if it is possible or not.

Comment: What is the problem with JSfiddle? Just adjust the top value for `right:before` to around `64px` and you will get that effect.

Comment: but what about the text in the middle of circle don't you notice everything? Also the smoothing with corners of border doesn't come up.

Comment: it is wise to draw the image and position it

Comment: is it not possible using CSS?

Comment: See the answer by @Orun Bhuiya. :)

Comment: the text should be in your example inside the element that covers part of the circle example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvKZKE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by adding another pseudo element so that the word "or" is not overlapped by other elements.

In the example below I've added a new `.right:after` almost identical to `.right:before`, except this element will be the one to display the text at a higher z-index.

See [this updated version of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/orvn/2re8d0cv/1/).

```
        .right:before {
            content:"";
            border: 1px solid #9F9F9F;
            width: 50px;
            height: 18px;
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            left: 175px;
            top: 65px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px 5px;
        }

       .right:after {
            content: "OR";
            width: 50px;
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            left: 175px;
            top: 65px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px 5px;
            z-index: 101
        }
```

*Edit: however, as you pointed out, this creates a 1 pixel gap near the border of the circle*
[image: 1 pixel gap]

We have to add a 4th and final pseudo element to cover up the borders from other elements that we don't want to see.

In other words, our previous pseudo element `.right:after` covers up the unwanted x-axis lines and the new `.left:before` covers up the y-axis lines.

```
            .left:before {
            content: "";    
            display: inline-block;
            height: 58px;
            width: 6px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 203px;
            top: 66px;
            z-index: 99;
            background-color: #FFF;
        }
```

Updated [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/orvn/2re8d0cv/2/).

[image: image showing elements]

Comment: can we have the smoothness on the border corners? If you notice what I mean?

Comment: Do you mean rounded corners, like with border-radius, or something else?

Comment: where it make 90 deg angle with box border and circle border, the should be connected to each other too. If you notice in my desired output. https://goo.gl/urTqDM

Comment: I see what you mean, there is a 1 pixel gap. Yes, this can still be done. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

## SVG

Here is a solution using <SVG>

Here is how it looks:

[image]

- Used path elements to draw the lines (with a curve in the center of the line)
- Placed the text in the center of the image. Then it looks like its in the center on the lines where they curve.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 400px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
}
.circlebetween {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  fill: white;
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-width: 0.7;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="right">RIGHT</div>
  <svg class="circlebetween" viewBox="0 0 20 100" perserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M 7,0 
               7,35
             A 15.1 15.1 0 0 0 7 65
             V100" />
    <path d="M13,0
             13,35
             A 15.1 15.1 0 0 1 13 65
             V 100" />
    <text x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" font-familiy="serif" stroke="none" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" transform="">OR</text>
  </svg>
  <div class="left">LEFT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Was suppose to be *it*, but i guess it was badly formed.